# angular2 import cropperjs

Tags: angular, cropperjs

In my Angular 2 application, I import [CropperJS](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs) as the following

1. npm install --save @types/cropperjs
   npm install --save cropperjs
2. In .angular-cli.json, add

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.js"
],
```

3. In app.component.ts. I import Cropper follow [this guide](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cropperjs/cropperjs-tests.ts)

```typescript
import * as Cropper from 'cropperjs';

// declare var Cropper: any
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'How Everything Work';
    @ViewChild('photo') photo: ElementRef;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {    
        var cropper = new Cropper(this.photo.nativeElement, {
               aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        });
    }

}
```

But when I run application, Cropper is undefined.
I also try to import Copper using

```
declare var Cropper: any
```

but it also doesn't work.
Did i miss something ?.
Thanks for any help.

### **Closed**.

I have found that, I just need to specify cropperjs into tsconfig.json and problem is solved.

```html
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ....
    ...
    "type":[
      "cropperjs"
    ]
  }
}
```

and in .angular-cli.json, we don't need to add cropper.min.js" to "scripts" field

```html
----> we don't need add cropper.min.js here
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.js"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

**1**. Install *cropperjs* package

```
npm install cropperjs --save
```

**2**. Install *cropperjs* TypeScript types for IDE support

```
npm install @types/cropperjs --save
```

**3**. In `angular-cli.json` add paths to `.css` and `.js` files

```
"styles": [
  ...
  "../node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
  ...  
  "../node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.js"
]
```

**4**. In `tsconfig.json` add cropperjs to `types` array

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types":[
      "cropperjs"
    ]
  }
```

**5**. In typings.d.ts add the following declaration

```
declare module 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.js' {
  import Cropper from 'cropperjs';
  export default Cropper;
}
```

**6**. Import *cropperjs* in your `.ts` file

```
import Cropper from 'cropperjs';
```